# Good quick reference parameters for discrete components

Tags: components, datasheet

I'm labeling and binning my discrete components.  I'm putting each component type in an envelope with its part number and a few key values.  The plan is that, when I need (say) an N-channel MOSFET that's at least 100 MHz, I can check the envelopes in my MOSFET bin and find one that meets the bill.  I also want key characteristics that I may need when designing common circuits, such as the voltage drop of a diode.

The first few lines on each envelope say something like "Transistor, NPN, small-signal / 2N2222A", and at the bottom I have a sketch of the package with E, B, C labeled.  I'm using small envelopes, and only have 5-6 lines for key characteristics.  For diodes, for instance, I have I<sub>F</sub>, V<sub>F</sub>, V<sub>RRM</sub>, P<sub>D</sub>, and T<sub>RR</sub>, although I'm not confident that I've got the best set of values there.

Obviously, if a characteristic is unusual or in the "Features" section of a datasheet (such as a particularly high frequency), I'd include it on the envelope for that part.  But otherwise, I'd like to come up with a good set of characteristics to include for each common component type (e.g., all my BJTs include h<sub>FE</sub>).

I'd like to come up with a good set of characteristics for diodes, BJTs, MOSFETs, op-amps, and other common components, like I laid out for diodes above.  Any opinions on the most important characteristics to put on the envelopes?

Comment: What are the parameters you first look at when checking a datasheet?

Comment: Put just the partnumber and the manufacturer on the envelope. Put the list of characteristics into an Excel sheet or similar. There are way too many parameters that you'd need to put on the envelope to be useful. putting them in a file gives you more freedom.

Comment: Very organised. I tend to label my envelopes with only part number, polarity, voltage and current. Anything else is superfluous, as for that level of detail I'd need to study the data sheet. The labels are only a pre-screen of which data sheets to study.

Answer (score 1):

WOW... that's an interesting approach. What information you add to the envelope is of course the problem, which is why you asked this question in the first place. Ultimately, what you need to add is open to opinion.

If it's a decent sized envelope you could simply cut out and stick the boilerplate specs from the sheet on the envelope..
[image]

However, ultimately, someone will need a number that's not there, and those numbers are fairly meaningless for many devices.

Why don't you do it on the computer instead. List your parts in a database with a location field so you can fetch them easily. e.g.: Cabinet number/shelf/rack/bin.. Then you can search the DB for the parts that meet your requirement rather than thumbing through envelopes.

You could also include a link to the full data-sheet for the part in the DB. You could also consider adding vendors, vendor part numbers, and pricing.

Comment: +1 for adding links and physical location of the stored component in the PC.

Comment: [Wrack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wrack_(seaweed)) [Rack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rack)

Answer (score 0):

For my Altium components, I use the **manufacturer's part number** as the key and the database has all the parameters that a distie such as Digikey provides (which means they are suitable for a parametric search). The short description is their description field, possibly modified, but usually not. Thus the database includes the pricing, links to datasheets etc. and includes the parameters that someone thought were important.

Individual physical drawers or whatever are marked with the "description" field. So a 2N2222AUATX (2N2222) might be **"TRANS NPN 50V 0.8A SMT"** rather than the detailed  "Bipolar (BJT) Transistor NPN 50V 800mA 500mW Surface Mount 4-CLCC (5.59x3.81)". Not perfect, but nothing is. Occasionally there are overlaps in manufacturer's full part numbers, but less often than you might fear. In that case, I just add a suffix to the number.

[image]

[image]

There is always going to be a bit of tension between using generic part numbers (such as for jellybean transistors and resistors) and using specific manufacturer's part numbers. One solution is to assign internal part numbers for generics and have a list of manufacturers and part numbers that meet the requirements.